# Solr search with multiple word in autocomplete

Tags: solr

I try to make a search by Solr using a file txt specified in sourceLocation attribute of suggest searchComponet. I've used this example:

## sample dict

```
hard disk hitachi
hard disk jjdd  3.0
hard disk wd    2.0
```

and make this query

```
host/solr/suggest?q=hard%20disk%20h&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.build=true
```

but the response is

> 03build304hard disk
>   jjddhard disk wdhard disk
>   hitachi31011hard disk
>   jjddhard disk wdhard disk
>   hitachi hard disk jjdd disk
>   hard disk jjdd

I want to have only one result, `hard disk hitachi`.
If i write a query with param q=hard disk , i've the same result and in collation tag is put  `hard disk jjdd disk`

it seems that search don't work on multi words

Can someone help me?

Comment: How do you configure the /suggest? And what "spellcheck.dictionary" you are using?